# Unable to retrieve the results using Spring JPA query that receives LocalDateTime as Input

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

I am using this code to get the current date and time

```java
LocalDateTime localDateTimeCurrent = LocalDateTime.now();
```

I then pass it to the repository using this line:

```java
List<Week> resultOriginDueDt  = weekRepository.findByOriginIdAndDueDateAfter(projectId,localDateTimeCurrent);
```

My Spring JPA methods look like this :

```java
List<Week> findByOriginIdAndDueDateAfter(UUID originId, LocalDateTime dueDate);
```

There are no results returned from the DB. The logs generated by my IDE show that the LocalDateTime is being bound to the JPA method as such:

```
Hibernate: select week0_.id as id1_7_, week0_.due_date as due_date2_7_, week0_.origin_id as origin_i3_7_, week0_.status as status4_7_ from week week0_ where week0_.origin_id=? and week0_.due_date>?
2021-02-08 01:50:46.621 TRACE 16320 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [38099ef1-cdb6-476f-80de-d76443b729db]

2021-02-08 01:50:46.621 TRACE 16320 --- [nio-8082-exec-9] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2021-02-08T01:50:46.620506800]
```

The current date in LocalDateTime format is `2021-02-08T01:50:46.671509700`

The dates are stored in the Database as such:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En6DI.jpg)

The format of the Dates in the table are as such : `2021-01-14 01:00:59`

If I take the query that is generated by Hibernate and run it using MySQL clients and change the date format to match the format in the Date db column it works.

The query

```sql
SELECT 
    week0_.id AS id1_7_,
    week0_.due_date AS due_date2_7_,
    week0_.origin_id AS origin_i3_7_,
    week0_.status AS status4_7_
FROM
    week week0_
WHERE
    week0_.origin_id = '38099ef1-cdb6-476f-80de-d76443b729db' AND week0_.due_date>'2021-01-09 01:00:59' ORDER BY due_date;
```

This one howeverr doesn't

```sql
SELECT 
    week0_.id AS id1_7_,
    week0_.due_date AS due_date2_7_,
    week0_.origin_id AS origin_i3_7_,
    week0_.status AS status4_7_
FROM
    week week0_
WHERE
    week0_.origin_id = '38099ef1-cdb6-476f-80de-d76443b729db' AND 
    week0_.due_date>'2021-02-08T00:33:10.897736400';
```

Please help me solve this problem. How can I make this query work. Thanks.

Comment: There are no records after than `2021-02-08T01:50:46.671509700`.

Comment: There is data, I can query them out when I use the MySQL workbench using one of the queries that I had given above.

Comment: Yes you are correct.